# Where should I place SDKs directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sdk, directory

I'm installing the Android SDKs on my Ubuntu system, and I do not want to place everything in my home directory.

For some reason, the LSB directory hierarchy is silent on where to place development kits. Is it more correct to create an /opt/sdks tree or /usr/local/sdks, or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: Are you trying to share one SDK install with multiple users? Other than that, is there some reason you're avoiding putting it in your home directory?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost up at you. I am always placing this stuff in my home directory under ~/development.

If you are the only user that needs to access the SDK. There is no need to place it somewhere else.

There is no strict rule for this!?!

Answer (score 0):

For optional things, there is /opt. For instance, QNX Software Development Platform (SDP, same as an SDK) installs there by default.